# remove commented block in xml ruby

Tags: ruby, xml

I'm required to write a script that can remove a commented block in xml file, and save it back to its directory.

```
    <Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">

    <!-- =========================================================== -->
    <!-- Server Thread Pool                                          -->
    <!-- =========================================================== -->
    <Set name="ThreadPool">
      <!-- Default queued blocking threadpool -->
      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool">
        <Set name="minThreads">10</Set>
        <Set name="maxThreads">10000</Set>
        <Set name="detailedDump">false</Set>
      </New>
    </Set>

    <!-- =========================================================== -->
    <!-- Set connectors                                              -->
    <!-- =========================================================== -->

      <!--
        <Call name="addConnector">
          <Arg>
              <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                <Set name="host"><SystemProperty name="jetty.host" /></Set>
                <Set name="port"><SystemProperty name="jetty.port" default="8983"/></Set>
                <Set name="maxIdleTime">50000</Set>
                <Set name="Acceptors">2</Set>
                <Set name="statsOn">false</Set>
                <Set name="confidentialPort">8443</Set>
          <Set name="lowResourcesConnections">5000</Set>
          <Set name="lowResourcesMaxIdleTime">5000</Set>
              </New>
          </Arg>
        </Call>
      -->        
    <Call name="addConnector">
  <Arg>
      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector">
        <Set name="host"><SystemProperty name="jetty.host" /></Set>
        <Set name="port"><SystemProperty name="jetty.port" default="8983"/></Set>
        <Set name="maxIdleTime">50000</Set>
        <Set name="lowResourceMaxIdleTime">1500</Set>
        <Set name="statsOn">false</Set>
      </New>
  </Arg>
</Call>

    </Configure>
```

on this xml 
 **How can I comment out this block only?**

```
<!--
   <Call name="addConnector">
      <Arg>
       <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
         <Set name="host"><SystemProperty name="jetty.host" /></Set>
         <Set name="port"><SystemProperty name="jetty.port" default="8983"/></Set>
         <Set name="maxIdleTime">50000</Set>
         <Set name="Acceptors">2</Set>
         <Set name="statsOn">false</Set>
         <Set name="confidentialPort">8443</Set>
         <Set name="lowResourcesConnections">5000</Set>
         <Set name="lowResourcesMaxIdleTime">5000</Set>
      </New>
    </Arg>
  </Call>
 -->
```

I have tried it with this but

```
  require 'nokogiri'

file = File.read("jetty.xml")
xml = Nokogiri::XML(file)

#replace <!-- --> with a space 
xml.xpath("//comment()").each do |node|
    node.content =node.content.gsub!(/(^\D\W[<!\-\-}]\W[\-\->])/,' ')
end

File.open("newjetty.xml","w") do |f|
    f.write xml.to_xml
end
```

this code only remove the text within the comment

Output:

```
     <!---->
        <!---->
        <!---->


 <Set name="ThreadPool">
      <!---->
      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool">
        <Set name="minThreads">10</Set>
        <Set name="maxThreads">10000</Set>
        <Set name="detailedDump">false</Set>
      </New>
    </Set>

        <!---->
        <!---->
        <!---->

      <!---->

        <!---->
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how can I uncomment a block in the xml

Comment: If you stuck to `Nokogiri`, you’d likely try to store `node.content`, then delete the entire comment node and add `node.content` there.

Comment: mudasobwa can you please give an example, I did use node.content

Answer (score 1):

You should delete the node, as it is a comment node. You can use the inner text to parse it and add it again.

```
require 'nokogiri'

file = File.read("jetty.xml")
xml = Nokogiri::XML(file)

#replace <!-- --> with a space 
xml.xpath("//comment()").each do |node|
    t = Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse(node.content)
    node.add_next_sibling(t)
    node.remove
end

File.open("newjetty.xml","w") do |f|
    f.write xml.to_xml
end
```

Here you are parsing the comments content, add it as the next sibling and remove the node itself.

This basically works, however the string-only contents are also added as nodes, making this a mixed content document, which you most certainly do not want for a jetty configuration file.

So there should also be some logic included that checks for the node type (text versus element) and only includes elements.

Comment: are comments referred as node in xml?

Comment: Yes, comment is a node type

Comment: so does that mean a node returns a list of node types?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. How can a node (being an object) return anything? Also, I have no knowledge of Ruby (this was my first ruby snippet ever, I think), so I am really of no help at all if you ask specific stuff about ruby or nokogiri.

Comment: i was asking with regard to the code snippet you gave me, it doesn't work when i run my script. thanks for your help

Comment: this code works on my machine, that's for sure. What do you mean with `doesn't work`, please give some concrete error description.

Comment: error: a document may not have multiplte root nodes (ArgumentError)